# Caught AttributeError while rendering: tuple object has no attribute regex

Tags: python, django

here is my urls.py and am currently getting the error: "tuple object has no attribute regex". Any thoughts?

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from ecomstore import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('ecomstore.accounts.views',
                       (r'^register/$', 'register', {'template_name':'registration/register.html', 'SSL':settings.ENABLE_SSL}, 'register'),
                       (r'^my_account/$','my_account', {'template_name':'registration/my_account.html'},'my_account'),
                       (r'^order_details/(?P<order_id>[-\w]+)/$', 'order_details', {'template_name':'registration/order_details.html'}, 'order_details'),
                       (r'^order_info//$', 'order_info', {'template_name':'registration/order_info.html'},'order_info'),
)

urlpatterns += ('django.contrib.auth.views', 
                (r'^login/$','login', {'template_name':'registration/login.html', 'SSL':settings.ENABLE_SSL}, 'login'),
)
```

Comment: You need to call `patterns()` on the second group of patterns, although I'm not sure this would give that attribute error on its own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot patterns around the second set of URL patterns. It should look like this:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
```

Comment: thanks - i've been staring at it for an hour :P. sometimes the easy ones are the hardest.